# separability of the Schatten-von-Neumann class

Tags: functional-analysis

My interest is to know whether the assertion : the class of Schatten-von Neumann of  operators  over a separable Hilbert space  is separable with respect to the $\|\cdot\|_p$ norm. 
is correct??
Thanks!